# WHy is my JSON not importing into Python Pandas?

Tags: json

For some reason, my JSON is not importing into Python.  I have tried using JSONlint but the error message I receive there seems to be conflicting with the one in Pandas.

Error: "Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)"

The JSON I am using is a Telegram chat history that I have imported - so I'm a little confused as to why it won't import.  Below is a sample:

```
{
 "name": "فاندامنتال | سرمایه گذاری مطمئن",
 "type": "public_channel",
 "id": 1151766431,
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": 1,
   "type": "service",
   "date": "2020-10-17T13:56:10",
   "actor": "فاندامنتال | سرمایه گذاری مطمئن",
   "actor_id": "channel1151766431",
   "action": "create_channel",
   "title": "استخراج رایگان بیت کوین | Free Bitcoin Mining",
   "text": ""
  },
  {
   "id": 3,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2020-10-17T14:10:51",
   "edited": "2021-10-12T17:47:45",
   "from": "فاندامنتال | سرمایه گذاری مطمئن",
   "from_id": "channel1151766431",
   "author": "unconquerablee",
   "text": "سلام دوستان امیدوارم حال همگی خوب باشه اگه هم خوب نباشه با این کانال خوب‌ میشه\n\nلطفا مطالب این کانال رو با دقت و با حوصله دنبال کنین \n\nیه فرصت خیلی عالی هستش برای داشتن درآمد به صورت دلار\n\n کاملا رایگان و بدون پرداخت حتی \n۱ ریال به هیچ شخص و هیچ نهادی \n\nدر این اوضاع اقتصادی و ارزش ارز این روش بهترین راه برای کسب درآمد هستش\n\nاین کانال در جهت مسائل بنیادی و فاندامنتال رمزارز ها فعالیت خواهد کرد.\n\n⁦️⁩پس قدم به قدم با ما همراه باشین"
  },
  {
   "id": 4,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2020-10-17T14:19:14",
   "edited": "2021-10-12T17:48:23",
   "from": "فاندامنتال | سرمایه گذاری مطمئن",
   "from_id": "channel1151766431",
   "author": "unconquerablee",
   "text": "صبور باشید تا دوستان بیشتری ملحق بشن تا باهم شروع کنیم.\n\nتعداد نفرات کانال : ۱۸نفر"
  },{
   "id": 9777,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2021-08-19T10:13:09",
   "from": "فاندامنتال | سرمایه گذاری مطمئن",
   "from_id": "channel1151766431",
   "reply_to_message_id": 9732,
   "photo": "photos/photo_8124@19-08-2021_10-13-09.jpg",
   "width": 1080,
   "height": 837,
   "text": [
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "نسبت #پوزیشن‌ها در صرافی های مختلف در 24 ساعت گذشته‼️"
    },
    "\n\nبــا مــا هـمـراه بــاشید\nکانال فاندامنتال | سرمایه‌گذاری مطمئن"
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": 9778,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2021-08-19T10:14:53",
   "edited": "2021-08-19T10:15:02",
   "from": "فاندامنتال | سرمایه گذاری مطمئن",
   "from_id": "channel1151766431",
   "reply_to_message_id": 9733,
   "photo": "photos/photo_8125@19-08-2021_10-14-53.jpg",
   "width": 1080,
   "height": 378,
   "text": [
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": " رمزارزهایی که در 24 ساعت گذشته بیشترین میزان لیکوئیدی را داشته اند‼️"
    },
    "\n\nو در کل 74,026  نفر در ۲۴ ساعت گذشته لیکوئید شده‌اند.\n\n",
    {
     "type": "text_link",
     "text": "بــا مــا هـمـراه بــاشید\nکانال فاندامنتال | سرمایه‌گذاری مطمئن",
     "href": "http://t.me/fundamental2020"
    },
    ""
   ]
  },
  {
   "id": 9779,
   "type": "message",
   "date": "2021-08-19T10:15:43",
   "edited": "2021-08-19T10:15:51",
   "from": "فاندامنتال | سرمایه گذاری مطمئن",
   "from_id": "channel1151766431",
   "reply_to_message_id": 9734,
   "photo": "photos/photo_8126@19-08-2021_10-15-43.jpg",
   "width": 1080,
   "height": 467,
   "text": [
    {
     "type": "bold",
     "text": "آمار لیکوئد شدن در صرافی‌ها در 24 ساعت گذشته‼️"
    },
    "\n\n بیش از 62 درصد پوزیشن‌های ",
    {
     "type": "hashtag",
     "text": "#Long"
    },
    " خرید ، لیکوئید شده‌اند\n\n",
    {
     "type": "text_link",
     "text": "بــا مــا هـمـراه بــاشید\nکانال فاندامنتال | سرمایه‌گذاری مطمئن",
     "href": "http://t.me/fundamental2020"
    },
    ""
   ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't edit your question yet, but you seem to be missing a ] and } at the end of your json sample.

After adding that though, I could load the json as long as I used the extra keyword argument `encoding='utf-8'`. As you haven't provided a code sample I cannot show you exactly where to add this keyword argument in your code, but here is the code I used to succesfully read the json:

```py
import json

x = json.load(open('SO JSON question/input.json', encoding='utf-8'))
print(x)
```